# Initialize a constant array of struct with bitfield

Tags: c, arrays, struct, bit-fields

I'd like to initialize a `const` array of structs. These structs have bitfield members.

Following is a snippet of my code:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned int a : 1;
    unsigned int b : 1;
    unsigned int c : 1;
} Character;

const static Character Char[] =
{
    {.a = 0, .b = 0, .c = 1},
    {.a = 0, .b = 1, .c = 0},
    {.a = 1, .b = 0, .c = 1}
};
```

When trying this way, I got many errors like `unexpected initialization syntax` and `missing ;`.

What is the right way to do this?

**UPDATE**

I'm using `COSMIC` compiler (`CXSTM8`). I checked its user guide but couldn't find any information in this regard.

Comment: How are you building the code? What are the compiler flags?

Comment: This is an embedded project. I'm using `COSMIC` compiler

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add information instead of answering in comments. Does the compiler support structure initialization with `.member = value`?

Comment: Compiles for me. Please produce a [mre]

Comment: The *Initializer List* has been introduced since C99. Do you have a switch to compile with C99? Is the Cosmic compiler compliant with C99?

Comment: `got many errors like` please post the exact error message from the compiler, at best including filename and line number and column number and at best including compiler invocation line. Please don't post "like" errors.

Comment: A better version would be `const static uint32_t ch[] = { C, B, A|C };`. This is extremely portable and deterministic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax you have given is correct. The **designated initializer list** was introduced in C99.

If your compiler does not support this, you need to go for the next best option. i.e. initialize all the members in the bitfield.

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned int a : 1;
    unsigned int b : 1;
    unsigned int c : 1;
} Character;

const static Character Char[] =
{
    {0, 0, 1},
    {0, 1, 0},
    {1, 0, 1}
};
```